# Cakephp: add Link into echo

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I have such a line of code

```
<?php echo __('This is text and the word TEXT has to be a link'); ?>
```

Is there any good trick to link the word "TEXT" to another href address? maybe without changing the entire structure? As I am using the i18n translation as the website is using 3 languages I want to keep the changes as minimal as possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to pass your link as an argument to __() function:

```
<?= __('This is text and the word {0} has to be a link', $this->Html->link(...)) ?>
```

More info can be found here: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#using-variables-in-translation-messages